# Reload a content almost invisibly and no blinking effect using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing a small progam wherein I'm getting data using $.get then display the data so far so good and then there's this part then when I click a certain link it refresh the page but it has this blinking effect. Is there a way on how to reload the content get the new updated content then replace the previously loaded data.

NOTE: I didn't use setInterval or setTimeout function because it slows down the process of my website. any answer that does not include those functions are really appreciated.

Here's the code

```
function EmployeeIssues(){
$('#initial_left').css({'display' : 'none'});
var table = $('#table_er');

$.get('admin/emp_with_issues', function(result){
    var record = $.parseJSON(result);
    var data = record.data,
        employees = data.employees,
        pages = data.pages;
    if(employees){

        $('#er_tab_label').html('<b>Employees with Issues</b>');
        for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
            $('#table_er').fadeIn('slow');
            table.append(write_link(employees[i]));  // function that displays the data
        }
        if(pages){
            $('#pagination').html(pages);
        }
    }else{
        $('#er_tab_label').html('<b>No employees with issues yet.</b>');
    }
});
table.html('');
}
```

then this part calls the function and display another updated content

```
 $('#refresh_btn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var tab = $('#tab').val();
    if(tab == 'er'){
        EmployeeIssues();
    }
});
```

What should I do to display the content without any blinking effect?
thanks :-)

Comment: a button that calls the EmployeeIssues function

Comment: @jily_101 do you have a sample in jsfiddle?

Comment: sorry but i don't have one

Comment: my only problem in that is the blinking of the table when it reloads

Comment: @jily_101 have you tried, first table.hide(), then when data is available table.show()

Comment: Haven't tried that one yet. I'll try it soon and tell you what happens

Answer (score 2):

This section might be the issue :

```
if(employees){
    $('#er_tab_label').html('<b>Employees with Issues</b>');
    for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
        $('#table_er').fadeIn('slow');
        table.append(write_link(employees[i]));  // function that displays the data
    }
    if(pages){
        $('#pagination').html(pages);
    }
} else ...
```

It seems you're asking table_er to fade in once per run of the loop whereas s there can only be one such table, you only need to do it once ?

first try re-arringing it like this:

```
if(employees){
   $('#er_tab_label').html('<b>Employees with Issues</b>');
   $('#table_er').hide(); // hide it while we add the html
   for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
       table.append(write_link(employees[i]));  // function that displays the data
   }
   $('#table_er').fadeIn('slow'); // only do this after the table has all its html

   if(pages){
       $('#pagination').html(pages);
   }
} else ....
```

Another possibility is that you're running through a loop and asking jquery to do stuff while the loop is running. It might be better to work out the whole HTML for the new page data in a string and then get the screen to render it in one line. I cna't do this for you as I don't know what's in write_link etc but something like this ..

```
if(employees){
   $('#er_tab_label').html('<b>Employees with Issues</b>');
   var sHTML ="";
   $('#table_er').hide(); // hide it while we add the html
   for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
      sHTML+=write_link(employees[i]); // maybe this is right ? if write_link returns an HTML string ?
   }

   table.append(sHTML);  // add the HTML from the string in one go - stops the page rendering while the code is running

   $('#table_er').fadeIn('slow'); // now show the table.

   if(pages){
       $('#pagination').html(pages);
   }
} else ...
```